# Excel formulas create

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Hello I have a problem with excel formulas **`=IFERROR(OR(IF(C2=INDEX(data!A2:A70126;MATCH(C3;data!B2:B70126;0));TRUE;FALSE);IF(C2=INDEX(data!A2:A70126;MATCH(C3;data!B2:B70126;0));TRUE;FALSE));FALSE)`**

I have a column A where is contain data for cell C2 and column B where is data for cell C3. But I have a problem when I search a match. for example:

**Column A (cell C2)  -----  Column B (cell C3)**

551-021  ---------------------              1055102000001

551-021    ---------------------          1055102000002

551-021    ---------------------         1055102000003

551-021    ---------------------          1055102000004

010.551-025  ---------------       1055102000000

010.551-025  ---------------    1055102000001

010.551-025    ---------------  1055102000002

010.551-025  ---------------    1055102000003

The problem is that for a different value in column "A" and cell "C2" with the same code from column "B", and the cells "C3"

When i search match 010.551-025 and 1055102000002 show me FALSE but for 551-021 and 1055102000002 show me TRUE. Do you know how can I repair it?

Thank you

Comment: I don't understand how Column A has multiple values if the column references a single cell (C2). I suspect you are getting FALSE matches as the values 010.551-025 are not originating from cell C2.  Please post a sample google sheet

Comment: I have at first sheet column A and column B where I have source data https://postimg.org/image/ihiakr817/   and at next sheet I have a cells "C2" (for value from column A) "C3" (for value from column B) and C4 (contain my code) where search match on positions. https://postimg.org/image/500kcly3l/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your index function `INDEX(data!A2:A70126,MATCH(C3,data!B2:B70126,0)` returns ***551-021*** when C3 = ***010.551-025***.
This why when you search match ***010.551-025*** and ***1055102000002*** shows FALSE and for ***551-021*** and ***1055102000002*** shows TRUE.

Use below mentioned Array Formula to get the desired result.

```
{=IF(OR(C2&"-"&C3=A1:A9&"-"&B1:B9),"True","False")}
```

Here Enter your data in Column A and Column B. Put values you want to search at C2 (value to be searched in Column A) and at C3 (value to be searched in Column B).

To write Array Formula press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER.

Comment: here is a link https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19k44wWRl0yye2yvp42o4N47igwub2oOnwgScVhg23xk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: check the link... i've entered the formula in sheet2... https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oQ4gPk1LBQHpbZ-xwqx2DXe7JLpyAoNqFKG0hL_L-mM/edit?usp=sharing